# Running bash commands written in a file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a file which contains the following commands,

```
export PATH=/gpfs/home/spandrekar/cse504/build_llvm/bin:$PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/gpfs/home/spandrekar/cse504/build_llvm/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/gpfs/home/spandrekar/cse504/build_llvm/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/gpfs/home/spandrekar/cse504/build_llvm/projects/openmp/runtime/src:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
```

I need to run these everytime I login to start my project. To make things easier, I am trying to run them using the command,

```
bash filename
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. When I type these commands on the commandline, it all works fine.

What am I missing here? How can I run the commands written in the file.

Comment: why not put them in your .bashrc file in your home directory ?

Comment: do `. filename`   , dot then filename

Comment: They're getting run -- in the new copy of bash you run with the command `bash`, which then exits when it's done. Once that shell has exited, the variables you assign are lost with it.

Comment: @PS. Doesn't work. Getting   .: .: is a directory.

Comment: @PS. Yes. It works! Thanks :)